# gorm: How to use slice as query destination

Tags: go, go-gorm

How to use slice as query destination.Here is the code I tried

```
var username []interface{}
db.Table("test_name").Select("username").Find(&username)
fmt.Println(username)
```

output `[<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in a pointer to a slice of your item kind

```golang
var username []TestName{} // or whatever you called it
db.Table("test_name").Select("username").Find(&username)
```